# How to link to certain page upon form submission using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm learning React Router and I have a simple Nav bar component that has an input/search bar in it. When search is clicked, it will search an API and I would like to use React Router to route to a new page (/results) to display the results.

I'd like to have my component `SearchResults` be displayed when the submit button is clicked.

This is my code:

```
const Search = () => {
  const apiKey = 'xxxxxx';
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchAPI();
  };

  const searchAPI = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=${input}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <Link to="/results">
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          search
        </button>
      </Link>
    </form>
  );
};
```

And these are my routes:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/results" component={SearchResults} />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

I expect the `<Link to="/results">` to automatically link to the /results page upon submit, but this is not the case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think `e.preventDefault()` is blocking the link, have you tried removing it?

Comment: You'd also have to get rid of the `form` tag which doesn't appear necessary here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a version of React that supports hooks. In this case, you can leverage the [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook from react-router which allows you to programmatically change routes.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Search = () => {
  const apiKey = 'xxxxxx';
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchAPI();
    history.push("/results");
  };

  const searchAPI = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=${input}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

The `Link` component from react router is conceptually just an anchor tag. That solution could work in this case, but you'd have to switch up the way your search works. You could have a `Link` component that pointed to `/results`, and then your `SearchResults` component could perform the search based on user input. In order for this to work you'd have to pass the value of `input` to `Link` so that you could access it later on. [Here are some ways you can pass extra data in the Link component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link).

Comment: @charlieyin If you include your `SearchResults` component, I'm happy to include more examples on how you could pull in query params from the URL and use those in your search.